# Windows 10 login error when working outside of corporate network

Tags: windows, login, active-directory, windows-domain, credentials

I get following error when I try to log on to my laptop while not on the corporate network:

> there are currently no logon servers to service the logon request

While connected on corporate network, I can log on successfully. I just can't log on if I am off corporate network.

This behavior has started quite suddenly because I never had this issue before. I also think this has started happening after I changed my domain password from another machine. So it's clear that something happened and now my laptop is not caching credentials any more.

Any pointers/diagnostic tips to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried asking corporate IT first?

Comment: I am currently bit far away and because I can't logon, I don't have access to websites with IT support info. I am hoping this might be more known issue.

Answer (score 3):

After changing your password, you need to log in once from within the corporate network. This way Windows can verify the new credentials against the logon server. Once you have done that, you can log in with your new password.

So, simple solution: go to the office, connect to the network, and log in. From then on, everything should work.